# Refresh ListView After SQLite update operations

Tags: android, sqlite

Creating a notepad application with CRUD operations.

I am trying to update the `ListView` item which contains titles for notes and on clicking open up the  respective Notes.

The contentvalues are succesfully showing the new values.

But the `ListView` is not updated with the updated note and instead continues showing the old one.

Here is the updated DBHandler:

```
   public class DBhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String DATA = "data";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + DATA + " text not null,"
            + TITLE + " text not null, "
            + DATE + " date "
            + " ) ; ";

    public DBhandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        this.db = db;
        String DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(DROP);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addNote(Note note) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String date = cal();
        values.put(DATA, note.getData());
        values.put(TITLE, note.getTitle());
        values.put(DATE, String.valueOf(date));
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);


    }


    public void delete() {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public void update(int id, String note, String title) {

        String date = cal();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     //   db.rawQuery("UPDATE notes set _id=id,data=note,title=title,date=date where _id=id",null);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, id);
        values.put(DATA, note);
        values.put(TITLE, title);
        values.put(DATE, String.valueOf(date));
       // Log.d("ValueNew", values.toString());
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM notes",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
      //  Log.d("DATABASE",cursor.getString(0)+ " "+cursor.getString(1)+ " "+cursor.getString(2));

        //  db.update();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int id) {
        String DEL = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " " + "WHERE  _id = " + id;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(DEL);
    }

    public String cal() {
        Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = " " + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" +
                (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
                ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " +
                ci.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +
                ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return date;
    }


}
```

Here is the EditNote class which calls update();

```
 public class EditNote extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    Button clear;
    EditText editNote;
    EditText editTextTitle;
    DBhandler dBhandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notecreate);
        editNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String newTitle = bundle.getString("newtitle");
        String newdata = bundle.getString("newdata");
        final int id = bundle.getInt("CursorId");
        dBhandler = new DBhandler(this);
        editTextTitle.setText(newTitle);
        editNote.setText(newdata);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
                String noteContent = editNote.getText().toString();
                // Log.d("IDNote",String .valueOf(id));
                Note note = new Note(id, noteContent, title);
                note.setId(id);
                note.setTitle(title);
                note.setData(noteContent);

                    dBhandler.update(id,noteContent,title);
                       // new ListNotesActivity().display();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new SaveNoteActivity().clear(editNote, editTextTitle);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And here is the ListNotesActivityClass :

```
 public class ListNotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView mListView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;
    DBhandler dBhandler;
    Cursor c;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noteslist);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
        registerForContextMenu(mListView);
        display();
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String data = (cursor.getString(1));
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListNotesActivity.this, ShowNote.class);
                intent.putExtra("Note", data);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo adapterContextMenuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int pos = adapterContextMenuInfo.position;
        c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(pos);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.update:
                String title=c.getString(2);
                String data=c.getString(1);
                Intent intent=new Intent(ListNotesActivity.this,EditNote.class);
                Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                extras.putInt("CursorId",pos);
                extras.putString("newtitle",title);
                extras.putString("newdata",data);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case R.id.deleteItem:
                dBhandler.getWritableDatabase();
                new DeleteItemClass().doInBackground(c);
                break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.listmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

        public void display() {
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
            dBhandler = new DBhandler(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dBhandler.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *  from " + DBhandler.TABLE_NAME, null);
            String[] titles = new String[]{DBhandler.TITLE, DBhandler.DATE};
             simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notetitle, cursor, titles, new int[]{R.id.noteTitleText, R.id.date}, 0);
          // simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
            simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        display();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.add:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListNotesActivity.this, SaveNoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                dBhandler.getWritableDatabase();
                SQLiteDatabase db = dBhandler.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from notes", null);
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                    dialog();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No items to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ListNotesActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void dialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Confirm");
        builder.setMessage("Are You Sure to Delete?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                new DeleteClass().doInBackground();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();


    }


    private class DeleteClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DBhandler> {
        @Override
        protected DBhandler doInBackground(Void... params) {
            dBhandler.delete();
            display();
            return dBhandler;


        }

    }

    private class DeleteItemClass extends AsyncTask<Cursor, Void, DBhandler> {
        @Override
        protected DBhandler doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
            dBhandler.deleteItem(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
            display();
            return dBhandler;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Note.java:

```
public class Note {
    String data;
    int id;
    String title;
    Note(){}
    Note(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }
    Note(String  data,String  title)
    {
        this.title=title;
        this.data=data;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    Note( int id,String data,String  title){
        this.data=data;
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;

    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bismeet can you post your full code it will be easier to help

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code.

Comment: Well there is android.view.Window.Callback error on calling display method from EditNote class .Maybe that helps.

Comment: Can you post the full error

Comment: Well now no errors but no updating of values in ListView. But if I  write something a column with a db.execSQL statement it works.

Comment: Eg this seems to work.

Comment: String update="UPDATE notes SET data = 'n'";
        db.execSQL(update);

Comment: That means the problem is with your update query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127278/discussion-between-bismeet-singh-and-ashish-shukla).

Comment: Bismeet I have posted the answer we found in chat and you can accept it ,So that the community will know the right answer to this question.

Comment: Bismeet you can remove your comments below the answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with your KEY_ID , you are updating an id thats not there in your database

thats why it is not refreshing your listview.

Just Change the id to something that is inside your database and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)

it will notify whenever any changes get commit on registered content provider.

as like :

```
 // Implement the onChange(boolean) method to delegate the change notification to
 // the onChange(boolean, Uri) method to ensure correct operation on older versions
 // of the framework that did not have the onChange(boolean, Uri) method.
 @Override
 public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
     onChange(selfChange, null);
 }

 // Implement the onChange(boolean, Uri) method to take advantage of the new Uri argument.
 @Override
 public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
     // Handle change.
 }
```

where...

> selfChange -->    boolean: True if this is a self-change notification.
>
> uri   --> Uri: The Uri of the changed content, or null if unknown.

Try it,

Happy Coding.

Comment: I aint got any idea about this.

Comment: I am not using any ContentProviders.